# AutoCloseable-ish method but runs only on catch

Tags: java

I would like to two have two different methods running in `catch` and `final` blocks. I have found `AutoCloseable` interface, but I need something to fire in case of exception only.
Like:

```
SomeService service = CreateService().andOpenTransaction()

try {
    service.doSomeMessyThingsInsideDB();
} catch (Exception e) {
    service.rollbackTransaction();
    throw e;
} finally {
    service.closeConnection();
}
```

Is there any way to make it simpler? As I said I am familiar with AutoCloseable, but it helps me only with finally block. I still cannot use it inside the catch.

Comment: There's no such interface for when exception is caught, auto-closeable is all there is. You could write a function with lambdas though.

Comment: Why do you have this transaction stuff external from the service to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could define your own interface, and then some `static` runner method:

```
public interface ErrorHandlingCloseable extends AutoCloseable {
     void run() throws Exception;
     void onError(Exception e);

     static void execute(ErrorHandlingClosable ehc) throws Exception {
         try(ErrorHandlingClosable temp = ehc) {
             ehc.run();
         } catch(Exception e) {
             ehc.onError(e);
             throw e;
         }
     }
}
```

Which you then could then call like this:

```
SomeService service = CreateService().andOpenTransaction();
ErrorHandlingCloseable.execute(new ErrorHandlingCloseable() {
    public void run() throws Exception { service.doSomeMessyThingsInsideDB(); }
    public void onError(Exception e) { service.rollbackTransaction(); }
    public void close() throws Exception { service.closeConnection(); }
});
```

But you see, it's still messy.

You could even implement this `interface` in your `SomeService` but then you're restricted that the `run()` method will always call `doSomeMessyThingsInsideDB()`.

---

Another way but still similar would be to use Java8 and create a helper functional `interface`:

```
public interface ThrowingRunnable {
   void run() throws Exception;
}
```

And then a `static` method somewhere:

```
public static void execute(ThrowingRunnable action,
                           ThrowingRunnable onCatch,
                           ThrowingRunnable onFinally) throws Exception {
   try(AutoCloseable ao = onFinally) {
       action.run();
   } catch(Exception e) {
       onCatch.run();
       throw e;
   }
}
```

The interesting part is probably this: `try(AutoCloseable ao = onFinally)`, which "registers" your `onFinally` method to be called when `finally` is reached.

This could then be called like this:

```
execute(
    service::doSomeMessyThingsInsideDB, 
    service::rollbackTransaction, 
    service::closeConnection
);
```

Comment: Your solution also missing `andOpenTransaction()` part.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov thanks, I've added it before the method is executed.

Comment: looks cool, but a bit overengeenered. Actually You answered my question, so points are going to you anyway :)

Comment: @Arkadiusz your welcome, I've added another way to do what you desire, by using Java8 functional interfaces. Which is still a bit, but less overengineered

Answer (score 1):

You said you are familiar with `AutoCloseable`, but you don't use it. 
Have you considered using `try-with-resources` statement?

Your code can be simplified to:

```
try (SomeService service = CreateService().andOpenTransaction()) {
    service.doSomeMessyThingsInsideDB();
} catch(exception e){
    service.rollbackTransaction();
    throw e;
}
```

Oracle has great [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for that, including examples.

**Note**: A try-with-resources statement can have catch and finally blocks just like an ordinary try statement. In a try-with-resources statement, any catch or finally block is run after the resources declared have been closed.

Answering your **question**, this is as simple as it can get. 
If your class doesn't implement `Closeable` then you can either implement it or use `finally`.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot use "service" variable in catch block. That is my problem.

Comment: if compiler would let me left the code the way you wrote I would have no problem at all. I am just looking for the best pattern :) looks like "try-with-resources" is not for me in this case. If noone will figure something out to the end of the day I will mark your answer as "the answer".

Answer (score 1):

***First step:*** Handling the exception

You evidently want the exception handled before some close. Then you need inside a try-with-resources to handle the exception.

```
/** throws RuntimeException */
void process(Callable<Void> work, Consumer<Exception> onFail) {
    try {
        work.call();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        onFail(e);
    }
}

try (SomeService service = CreateService().andOpenTransaction()) {
    process(() -> service.doSomeMessyThingsInsideDB(),
            e -> {
                service.rollbackTransaction();
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            });
}
```

This is not very satisfactory, but again also integrating the AutoCloseable, might give too few use-cases.

***Second step:*** with AutoCloseable

```
<SV extends AutoCloseable> void processAutoClosing(Supplier<SV> serviceFactory,
                                               Callable<Void> work, Consumer<Exception> onFail) {
try (SV service = serviceFactory.get()) {
    process(work, onFail);
}

}

processAutoClosing(...);
```